# July 10th Windows update broke IIS using .NET DLL exposed as COM object

Tags: .net, iis, asp-classic

We found that as people started getting the 2018 July 10th windows updates that one of the COM objects we created in VB.NET 2012 no longer can be created using classic ASP.  You get the dreaded "Cannot create ActiveX object" error when you do a Server.CreateObject in ASP. If you uninstall the  Windows update KB4338420 then the ActiveX control works again. We found this article on that KB update that states "The update addresses the vulnerability by correcting how .NET Framework activates COM objects." This may be the issue but I was wondering if anyone else just started having this problem too and found a way to change the COM object, if this is the problem, so the update would not break the functionality. Here are the references:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4338420/description-of-the-security-and-quality-rollup-for-net-framework-4-6-4

https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-8202

Comment: Same problem, I lost the whole day for this...

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar issue with Crystal Reports using User Defined Library (UFL)
Change the UAC to higher level then none seem to fix the issue for now